# Overloaded method does not use double input

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm trying to create console app to understand method overloading.
I got Class lib like this

```
namespace GetStringName
{
    public class GetString
    {
        public void Player(double num)
        {
            double number = num * 2;
            Console.Write(number);
        }
        public void  Player(string name)
        {
            char[] charr = name.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charr);
            Console.Write(charr);
        }   
    }
}
```

And I got my Console app like below

```
using GetStringName;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetString y = new GetString();
            y.Player(Console.ReadLine());           
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And whatever I type (string or integer) it always does the revert string thing.
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline) returns a string. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `Console.ReadLine()` method returns string. If you `TryParse` your input and if it is a `double` it will call method for `double`, otherwise it will call method for `string`. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    GetString y = new GetString();
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    double doubleInput;

    if(double.TryParse(input, out doubleInput)) {
        y.Player(doubleInput);
    } else {
        y.Player(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() will always return a string regardless of what you place into you input. In order to parse your input as a double you need to use either double.Parse or double.TryParse.

Examples:

```
double input;
bool success = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
if(success)
{
    y.Player(input);
}
```

Or

```
try
{
     y.Player(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
}
catch(FormatException)
{
     //Input is not a double
}
catch(OverflowException)
{ 
     //Input is out of bounds for a double type 
}
```

TryParse will return a bool indicating if the parse was successful or not while Parse will throw an exception if the input is invalid.

Generally, I always prefer TryParse unless you specifically want to let the user know why their input is not valid.

Answer (score -1):

you need to provide double as a parameter to a method 
try this

```
 y.Player(Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Comment: What if the user enters a non-parseable value?

Comment: this is another question. I answered the topic, why he fall to string overload.

Comment: of course. The full solution is provided by Stradivarius above.